# Why consoles/terminals usually have a black background?

Tags: desktop-application, color-scheme

In unix and window systems, the console has a black background. Is this historical or is there any UX reasoning behind it?

I'm working on a web based terminal and giving the window the look and feel of a terminal. When it comes to background color, I was torn between black, white or any other color.

Additionally, MacOS uses a white background as the default terminal background. Is there any reason for choosing black or white background for terminals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this

> Terminal application is a program designed to emulate old terminals for example the VT100. In those "devices" where monitors, where the letters where "drawn" by illuminating some pixels, initially in green or orange and the most modern in white.

Follow to know more - [Why is the background color of cmd/BIOS/Terminal black while Internet browser's is white?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-background-color-of-cmd-BIOS-Terminal-black-while-Internet-browsers-is-white)

Comment: So we can assume that it is because of historical reason?

Comment: Yes... we can assume